# Android: SurfaceView ignoring postInvalidate()?

Tags: android, surfaceview, ondraw

It's the first time I'm using this so I'm not sure whether its a bug in my code or I'm trying to do something thats not allowed.

Currently, I have a DrawThread() which does this in the run method.

```
try {
  c = m_surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
  synchronized (m_surfaceHolder) {
    m_view.onDraw(c);
  }
}
finally {
  if (c != null) {
    m_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
  }
}
```

While in this drawing thread (non UI-thread), my onDraw() method passes the canvas along to another method called drawScoreboard(). I wanted this method to have a short delay between displaying each row of the scoreboard, so I added a postInvalidateDelay(x) hoping it would trigger onDraw() again.

```
/**
 * A helper function which draws the scoreboard.
 */
private void drawScoreboard(Canvas canvas) {
  long delay = m_drawScoreboard.draw(canvas, m_paint);

  if (delay > 0) {
    this.postInvalidateDelayed(delay);
  }
}
```

The code executes correctly and postInvalidateDelayed() IS being called, but I'm baffled to why onDraw() is not being called. Are there any flags or initialisation I need to do in order to get this to work?

Any advice or theories are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: SurfaceView calls setWillNotDraw(true), which might ignore this call. Please try setting this to false and see if draw is getting called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You bloody legend Karan!

That pointed me in the right way.
I found a few posts that mentioned it had to be done in the **surfaceCreated()** method rather than constructor and it got the **postInvalidate()** working.

However, enabling that would disable any drawing done by my custom *DrawThread*.
Good thing is it should be easy to find a nice point in time to slot in that call.

Thanks again, **View.setWillNotDraw()** did the trick.