# Android postinvalidate does not invoke onDraw()

Tags: c#, android, ondraw

Setup:

Activity's layout has a SurfaceView object (obj) with the SurfacHolder callbacks defined.  obj has the following thread defined (this is written in C# via Xamarin) :

```
    void DrawThread() {
        Canvas c;
        while (drawingThreadActive) {
            c=null;
            try {
                c = this.Holder.LockCanvas(null);
                lock(Holder) {
                    //force redraw
                    PostInvalidate();
                } 
            } finally {
                if (c!=null) {
                    this.Holder.UnlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            //sleep for 50 ms or so (20Hz refresh)
        }
    }
```

The `SurfaceCreated()` callback is called just fine, which starts this thread.  However, the call to PostInvalidate() never results in the `onDraw()` function being called.

I'm pretty sure everything is setup correctly - any idea what I'm missing?

Given that the `SurfaceCreated()` method is called, I am assuming it is 'visible in the UI'

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm guessing `DrawThread` isn't running on the main thread, is that so?

Comment: How do I determine what/where the main thread is?  I tried making DrawThread() call Invoke but that failed, so it's not on the main thread.. Given that it's its own thread, wouldn't that mean that it can't be on the main thread?

Comment: Please, post relevant code where you're calling `DrawThread`

Comment: DrawThread is a thread.. backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrawThread));  backgroundThread.Start(); called in `SurfaceCreate()` - though problem is solved, look below..

Comment: Great, glad you found it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here - this post can be marked as duplicate. : [Android: SurfaceView ignoring postInvalidate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479907/android-surfaceview-ignoring-postinvalidate)

For some reason, SurfaceView defaults to 'it will not draw'.  Calling `SetWillNotDraw(false)` in `SurfaceCreated()` fixes.